# PyTube printing video resolutions

Tags: python, pytube

Is there a way to print all the video resolutions clearly

```
from pytube import YouTube

# enter video URL
video_url = ""

# create youtube thing
yt = YouTube(video_url)

# Get list of all resolutions
resolutions = []
for stream in yt.streams.filter(progressive=True):
    resolutions.append(stream.resolution)

# sort resolutions and print
resolutions.sort()
print("Available Resolutions: ")
for res in resolutions:
    print(res)
```

Output for this code:

```
Available Resolutions: 
144p
360p
720p
```

but there is more resolutions why cant i see and i want to print all of them clear like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print all available video resolutions for a YouTube video using PyTube, you can do the following:

1. Include both progressive and adaptive streams.
2. Use a set to store unique resolutions and filter out audio-only streams.
3. Sort and print the resolutions.

Here's the code:

```
from pytube import YouTube

video_url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbmS3tQJ7Os"  # Enter the video URL

yt = YouTube(video_url)
resolutions = sorted(
    {stream.resolution for stream in yt.streams if stream.resolution},
    key=lambda x: int(x[:-1]),
)

print("Available Resolutions:")
for res in resolutions:
    print(res)
```

You can change my video (`"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbmS3tQJ7Os"`) with any video you like.